# How to add a dictionary to a ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, contextmenu

I am currently trying to add to a context menu strip a dictionary of status values. The main issue I am having is how to pass in the Key value of the selected dictionary item to a click event.

```
Dictionary<int, string> statusList = getStatusList();

if (statusList.Count > 0)
{
    Dictionary<int, ToolStripItem> statusMenu = new Dictionary<int, ToolStripItem>();

    foreach (var keyValuePair in statusList)
    {
         statusMenu.Add(keyValuePair.Key, new ToolStripMenuItem() { Text = keyValuePair.Value.ToString(), Image = Resources.Refresh });
         //statusMenu[statusMenu.Count - 1, statusMenu].Click += new EventHandler(MenuOption_Click_Handler); This is where I am confused
    }
    datagridview1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Set Status to", Resources.Refresh, statusMenu.Values.ToArray()));
}
```

I can easily get the array of the dictionary values. I am just wondering if its possible upon clicking a status in the contextmenu to pass the Key to a save method?

So, for example say statusList contains the following values:
{[1, Status1]}
{[2, Status2]}
{[5, Status3]}

So if I load the contextmenu, if I click Status3, I need to pass to the ClickEvent that Status Key 5 was clicked. Right now its only detecting the Value (Status3). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but i really don't understand what do you want after reading 10 times :(

Comment: One way would be to set the `Tag` property of the `ToolStripItem` to the value of the Key.  The event handler will have a reference to the item that was clicked (sender) and you can get the key value from the `Tag` property.

Comment: How would I go about setting the tag property?

Comment: When you loop through the `Dictionary` and create the `ToolStripMenuItem`s,  set `Tag = keyValuePair.Key` at the point where you're setting the `Text` and `Image` properties.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway This looks good, but I'm only having issues now with adding a click event. statusMenu[StatusMenu.Values.Count - 1].Click += new EventHandler(MenuOption_Click_Handler). Any ideas?

Comment: Sooner or later you are going to regret Dictionary, it is not an ordered collection.  Use SortedDictionary.  Which in turn makes you consider List, now the code gets simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you rename your tooltip control? The id is the key of `Dictionary`, so it should be distinct. Anyway, any control must have name.

This is an idea. You name the control with the prefix `ToolStrip`(or whatever you like) + `Key` and get it later. Like:

```
var newItem= new ToolStripMenuItem() { 
Text = keyValuePair.Value.ToString(), 
Image = Resources.Refresh,
Name="ToolStrip" + keyValuePair.Key };

newItem.Click +=new EventHandler(MenuOption_Click_Handler);
statusMenu.Add(keyValuePair.Key,newItem);
```

In `MenuOption_Click_Handler` method:

```
public void MenuOption_Click_Handler(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Name.Substring(0,9));
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, I am now just stuck on dynamically adding the click event to each status. stausMenu[statusMenu.Values.Count-1].Click += new EventHandler(MenuOption_Click_Handler). I assume the error I'm getting with this is that I am missing something with the dictionary, but I'm not sure the syntax. Thank you for your help

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.' I believe it has to be dealing with that my dictionary is of type <int, ToolStripItem> and I am doing something wrong with my indexing.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works now. Before I accept this answer, could you explain why I need to initialize a new toolstripmenu variable instead of the way I was originally thinking?

Comment: I don't really understand your code. I follow my methodology, all property of object should init at the same time and add it later. I think you were bad manipulate your dictionary. That all. Debug to find down